# How do I display the value of an integer variable in a UILabel field? (Beginner)

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

My current code is set so that when a button is pushed, the label properly displays "Brendan" using this implementation code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
displayLabel.text= @"Brendan";
}
```

Instead of the string "Brendan" , I would like to display the value of an integer variable called "score".

This is the code that I keep wanting to enter but its clearly wrong. I just don't understand how to do it.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
displayLabel.text= @"%i",score;
}
```

I am guessing you cannot reference an integer variable using the displayLabel.text method. What would the correct solution be?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`displayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];`